# Read a file from text box without giving file type in input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to read the file when I paste the path in text box and when I click the file read button. The problem is that it's not reading -- but for input tag with file option it is reading.

Can you guys tell me how to achieve it? Providing my code below.

https://codepen.io/texirv/pen/dzwrqM?editors=1111

```or-tag-here
<input class="laptop" placeholder="Paste link here to upload document." type="text" name="sportsBox" id="sportsBox">

$("#swimmingLink").click(function() {
      console.log("inside click function--->" );
            playerValue = $("#sportsBox").val().replace(/\\/g,"/");
            var coffee = playerValue.substring(playerValue.lastIndexOf('/')+1)

            console.log("playerValue--->" + playerValue);
            console.log("coffee--->" + coffee);

            //var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
            var myReader = new FileReader();

            //var textType = /text.*/;
            var file = playerValue.files[0];
            console.log("file---->" + file);
```

Comment: onpaste Event.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_onpaste.asp. You are trying to read the value in the wrong moment.

Comment: @PedroSouki hey I tried but not able to achieve using on paste... can you update in my fiddle

Comment: A web page cannot read a file in that manner. It can access only files that a user explicitly chooses through a file input or drags and drops on the browser from file explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this cannot be achieve due to security reasons.

The only way you can get the file when a user selects it by own.

Else, anybody can run some simple script from the console to upload thousands of malicious files on your app/server. That is why you need an input with a type file.